# Condition for no centripetal acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, centripetal-force

In my high school, I just got to learn a bit about centripetal force.

My question is if a body already at rest is introduced into outer space above the atmosphere,will it gain centripetal acceleration and start orbiting the earth?

Will it stay wherever it is?

Or will it start falling down the surface(you  know force is constantly acting on it)?

Also, why is the mass of large body not taken into consideration while calculating centripetal force?

Please give me some intuitive explanation.I'm totally new to this

Comment: The mass of the body is important for centripetal force.  The centripetal acceleration can be determined from velocity and curvature.  The force required to achieve that centripetal acceleration still depends on the mass.

Answer (score 3):

"Centripetal" is just a description of which way a force is pointing; it is not some special force that comes out of nowhere. For example if I tie a rope to a bucket, I can now swing the bucket around in circles. The only way that I can do this is to pull on the rope while the bucket is moving sideways relative to me: this force which points from the bucket to me (via the rope) is called "centripetal" because it points towards the center of the circle, but that word does not tell you the *source* or *cause* of that force (me and the rope), just the *direction* of that force.

If an object is released at rest some height above the surface of the Earth, it will eventually fall to Earth due to Earth's gravitational force. That's not 100% true and there are exceptions because there's more stuff in space than just the Earth (so you might fall into, say, the Moon or Jupiter or the Sun or a different star instead, or you might fall into a place like the L2 or L3 Lagrange points where the forces from various objects in space cancel out) and because space itself is expanding there's probably a distance where Newtonian gravitation no longer will get you back to the Earth faster than the expansion of space takes you away from it. But I mean if you're close enough and nothing else gets in the way you will fall to Earth.

However, if something moves sideways with respect to Earth, then while it falls "down" it also moves "sideways" a little bit. Now when things near the surface of Earth fall, they fall in parabolas, where $x(t) = u_x ~t + x_0, ~~ y(t) = -\frac12 a t^2 + u_y t + y_0,$ and the initial velocity was $\vec u = (u_x, u_y)$, and the initial position was $\vec r_0 = (x_0, y_0).$ As you get higher it turns out that this force attracting you to the Earth gets weaker and you become less interested in the direction "down" and more interested in the direction "Earthward:" for us on the surface these two are the same direction, but if you are very far into space even moving a single step "left" or "right" might cause the Earth to not be directly "beneath" you. But this gravitational force still pulls you "Earthward."

Now if the Earth were just one single point, and had no size, then *any* sideways motion would mean that you would not crash into Earth. Instead you'd "orbit" the Earth in an ellipse, with the Earth as one focus of the ellipse. You'd "miss" the Earth when you fell down because of your sideways motion; you'd get very close travelling very fast, but then you would "miss" it and come right back out to where you were. But the Earth is a bit larger, so a lot of these ellipses crash into the Earth's surface.

Nevertheless, if you go fast enough, you will eventually find yourself in an ellipse which misses the surface entirely and then you will be in "orbit." (You have to go a little bit further away in order to also miss the atmosphere, but that's practically nothing; the Earth is something like 13,000 km wide and the atmosphere is only a couple km on either side.)

Some of those ellipses are circles. Circular orbits are very nice. The position vectors look like $\vec r(t) = [x(t), y(t)] = [R \cos(\omega t), R \sin(\omega t)]$ and these trigonometry functions $\sin$ and $\cos$ are really nice to deal with, especially with calculus. It turns out that in any such uniform circular motion the velocity is $\vec v(t) = R\omega [-\sin(\omega t), \cos(\omega t)]$ and the acceleration is $\vec a(t) = R\omega^2 [-\cos(\omega t), -\sin(\omega t)],$ therefore $\vec a = -\omega^2 ~\vec r$ and $|\vec v| = \omega R.$

This leads to a very nice formula that the amount of centripetal acceleration you need to travel around a circle of radius $R$ with tangential speed $v$ is $\omega^2 R = (v/R)^2 R = v^2/R.$ You don't need to have understood all of how I got to that in order to appreciate the result and there are lots of ways to derive it.<sup>1</sup>

So how does mass factor into this? It says that you need a bigger force to orbit in a particular circle! Because you need the *same acceleration* but force is always mass times acceleration.

On the other hand, for *gravity* your force is automatically proportional to mass and inversely proportional to the square of the distance.  So for this particular case of gravitational orbits you have $$\frac{G M m}{R^2} = \frac {m v^2}{R}$$ and then $GM = v^2~R$ is the information you need for orbits. (In fact we don't know the exact numerical value of this constant $G$ very well, so often in space we know this product $GM$ with much more accuracy than we know the mass of an individual planet, because we can just look at things like orbits' $v^2 R$ parameters and figure it out to very high accuracy.)

1. Okay, since you are curious, here's a second way, 'cause it's one of my favorites. You can just start with the formula for a circle, $y = \sqrt{R^2 - x^2},$ and approximate it with a parabola for small $x$. Your teacher will tell you that $\sqrt{1 - \epsilon} \approx 1 - \frac12 \epsilon$ for very small $\epsilon$, and we can pull out a factor of R to find $y = R \sqrt{1 - (x/R)^2} \approx R (1 - \frac 12 (x/R)^2) = R - \frac12 x^2/R.$ You can then equate that expression for $y(x)$ with the above $x(t), y(t)$ expression for $u_y = 0, x_0 = 0, y_0 = R.$ If you just call $u_x = v$ then you have $x = v t$ and therefore $t = x/v,$ so you also have $y = R - \frac12 a (x/v)^2.$ The only way these parabolas are the same is if $1/R = a/v^2,$ and you again get $a = v^2/R.$ There are lots of ways to see that this is the "correct" formula for centripetal acceleration.

Comment: +1 that's a much better answer than mine, but I do think the OP needs to deal directly with the teacher, more than anything we can do here...

Answer (score 1):

When we launch a satellite into space, say to orbit the earth, we have to give the  satellite velocity to orbit the earth, and this is around 17,000 mph, otherwise it will fall back to Earth. Go on YouTube and watch a shuttle launch, you will see it gradually tip over from vertical onto its "back".

It has got high enough, but height alone is not enough, it needs to keep that vertical velocity and change it into horizontal velocity.

There are plenty of sites that explain this, look up Wikipedia or search NASA sites.

Answer (score 0):

First of all centripetal force is the one which changes the velocity of body (actually direction and not magnitude) going along some curve. In absence of it body will continue to move along a straight line.

[image]

For example consider body moving in circle around center with constant speed. Velocity of body points upward at point A while it points towards left at point B. So even though the magnitude of velocity is same, velocity is not constant. Change in velocity means there is an acceleration and hence some force. This force is called the "Centripetal Force" ans corresponding acceleration the "Centripetal acceleration". Note that to keep the magnitude of velocity constant, at any moment of time, centripetal force cant have a component along the velocity and hence it is always perpendicular to the velocity.

Now, this centripetal force can be provided by any other force which can be tension in string if you are swirling stone tied to string, or it can be gravitational pull if you consider satellite orbiting earth.

> will it gain centripetal acceleration and start orbiting the earth?

Centripetal acceleration cant be gained, it has to be there if body wants to go round some curve.

> Will it stay wherever it is?
>   Or will it start falling down the surface(you know force is constantly acting on it)?

Yes, it will start falling on the surface. The body has no initial velocity. The only force on body is towards the surface. So is its acceleration. So it will fall directly towards the surface. But had the body been given some initial tangential velocity, the initial velocity would have been horizontal and acceleration would have been vertically downward which would have changed the direction of velocity and as gravity is providing the required force and acceleration, it would have said be providing "Centripetal acceleration". Note that acceleration is present in both the cases. The only difference is that, in later case it contributes to changing the direction.

Also, in later case, just after initial moment, velocity and acceleration will no longer be perpendicular. In that case, component of acceleration perpendicular to velocity at any moment will contribute in changing its direction and hence will provide centripetal acceleration. While the component parallel to velocity will change the magnitude of velocity (and is called tangential acceleration).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve circular motion around the Earth the satellite need to have a velocity tangent to the orbit it will take around the earth. In satellite motion, there is a balance between the satellite's velocity trying to take it away from Earth, on a tangent (v in the diagram) and gravity pulling it back to Earth (g in the diagram). When, as the diagram shows, the amount that v takes it further away from the orbital path is equal to the fall back to Earth, g, then the satellite orbits at a [relatively] fixed distance. (Most orbits are elliptical to some degree but the same general idea applies).
[image]

Mass doesn't matter. In your class you may see a mathmatical proof of this but here is a simple explaination. It the satellite were twice as massive, there would be twice the gravitational force pulling it to Earth. But the greater mass makes it twice as resistant to motion. It has more inertia, resistance to a change in motion, due to its greater mass. Twice the gravity acting on twice the mass, with twice the resistance to motion, results in the same acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Teachers often gloss over the details of rotational frames.  Your teacher may have done the same.

The best way to approach this is a bit backwards.  In many circumstances we start with the forces (such as by drawing a free body diagram), and then we work our way to accelerations.  For this topic, it's actually easier to approach centripetal *acceleration* first.  Then, if need be, we can talk about a centripetal or centrifugal force later if its convenient.

The most important thing to understand about centripetal acceleration is that its caused by rotation of the frame you're using to measure data.  Remember, the Earth is spinning.  If you think about "a body at rest" and you're thinking in a spinning frame, you'll see centripetal accelerations.  If the frame is not spinning, you wont.

Let's talk inertial coordinates for a moment.  Inertial coordinates have all sorts of properties, but their key property for this discussion is **In an inertial frame, Newton's first law, the law of inertia, is satisfied: Any free motion has a constant magnitude and direction.** ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference)).  In such a frame, Netwon's second law looks like the familiar $F=ma$.

Going to your question, if a body "at rest" in an inertial frame is introduced above our atmosphere, it will obey $F=ma$.  The only acceleration on this body would be gravity, so the object would plummet straight down.  Boring, but true.

Of course, it wont *look* like its going straight down to an observer on the ground.  This is because the Earth is rotating.  If you were directly underneath the body in space when it was introduced, it would begin dropping towards you, but you would start rotating away from it!  To you, it would look like the object is curving away from you.

This inertial frame is convenient because the equations of motion are exactly as simple as you want to be.  However, it's inconvenient in a lot of ways.  For example, we like the idea that a Book, lying on a table, is "at rest."  In fact, in an inertial frame, it's zipping along at over 200m/s due to the rotation of the earth... but we'd love to not have to think about that.  We'd love to see a speed limit that says 50mph and not have to think "oh that's 497 mph going with the rotation of the earth, but 503 going against it."  That's just not how we want to think.

The solution is to introduce rotating frames.  You can think of these like a coordinate system that is constantly rotating.  One of the more important ones for any discussion of space is ECEF.  This is a coordinate system that's centered on the center of the Earth, and it rotates at the rate of the Earth's rotation.  This is a really convenient frame to operate in, because it means objects that look like they're sitting still on the surface of the earth actually have 0 velocity in this frame... they're "at rest."

So what if we had an object in space "at rest" in this rotating ECEF frame?  To be "at rest" in this frame means the object must be orbiting the earth.  This means it must have a velocity in the *inertial frame*, and must have an acceleration pulling it towards the center of the earth *in the inertial frame*.  For a body in orbit, the only force acting on the object is gravity, so the force of gravity *must* be equal to the mass of the object times the acceleration needed to maintain that orbit.  If they weren't equal, we simply wouldn't say this object is in orbit, and thus would not be "at rest" in our rotating frame.

So, this is all fine and dandy.  However, what happens if we try to calculate the motion of this object in our rotating ECEF frame?  We see gravity pulling it down (because gravity doesn't go away), but the object remains "at rest."  Why?  Well, if you run the calculus equations regarding motion in an inertial frame and then transform them into a rotating frame, you'll find the motion of the object is no longer governed quite by $F=ma$.  We see the math actually says the equation is $F=m(a+\frac{v^2}{r})$ (here's the [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force) if you're curious).  That $\frac{v^2}{r}$ term is the "centripital acceleration."  If you use this equation correctly, you'll find that your object 'at rest in the ECEF frame' is pulled down by gravity exactly matches that of the centripetal acceleration term, leaving $a=0$, which is required for an object at rest.  If they were not exactly equal, we wouldn't call the object "at rest" in the rotating frame.  It'd have some velocity or acceleration to deal with.

Now if you want, you can rearrange the terms to get $F-\frac{mv^2}{r}=ma$.  Phrased this way, it looks like a "centrifugal force," canceling out the force of gravity.  This is called a "ficticious force" because it's really an artifact of our rotating coordinate system.  It isn't a real force.

This shows why the mass of the large object isn't considered.  It actually *does* appear as part of the gravity term.  However, we can see that the centripetal effects are *actually* acceleration terms, and don't include any masses at all.  The only reason we have to include the mass is if we choose to model the effect as a force, rather than an acceleration.